# Preserve selected model row in sorted JTable across model update

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm having difficulties getting the following code to preserve the logically selected row in the model if the JTable has been sorted.

It works as intended when no sorting is applied.

```
private void updateAccountTable() {
    accountsTable = guiFrame.getAccountsTable();

    // Preserve selected model row
    String accountNumber = "";
    int selectedRow = accountsTable.getSelectedRow();
    if(selectedRow >= 0){
        accountNumber = (String)accountsTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
    }

    // Preserve sort order
          // Keep eclipse happy.  better way??
    List <? extends SortKey> keys = accountsTable.getRowSorter().getSortKeys();

    // Update displayed accounts
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) accountsTable.getModel();
    model.getDataVector().clear();

    Object[][] tableContents = accountList.getAccountsAsArray(true);
    model.setDataVector(tableContents, tableHeaders);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();

    // reset sort order
    accountsTable.getRowSorter().setSortKeys(keys);

    // If updated model contains previously selected account, reselect
    if (!accountNumber.equals("") && null != accountList.getAccount(accountNumber)){
        for (int row=0; row<accountsTable.getRowCount(); row++){
            String an = (String)accountsTable.getValueAt(row, 0);
            if (an.equalsIgnoreCase(accountNumber)){
                accountsTable.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        accountsTable.clearSelection();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately setRowSelectionInterval() doesn't updated the selected row as expected, despite being called with the correct view row number.  It seems to do nothing.

.....So,

Why is setRowSelectionInterval() failing to updated the selection, or what have I missed?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Fair point.  Is this URL still valid?  This (and all the other links to sscce.org) fails to load for me

Comment: Sorry, the SSCCE server is a little dodgy at the moment.  Am looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

The `row` obtained from `getSelectedRow()` is in *view* coordinates, while the *model* coordinates have been changed by the intervening update. Quoting from the relevant [tutorial section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection):

> This distinction does not matter unless your viewed data has been rearranged by sorting, filtering, or user manipulation of columns.

You will need to use the conversion methods described near the end of [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), which suggests:

> When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates.

Comment: getSelectedRow() is only used to populate selectedRow in order to populate the accountNumber variable at the very begining. This all happens within the view context.  The row variable used to try and set the selection interval is an loop variable that is also in view context after the data has changed.  Does setRowSelectionInterval expect a row number in the model context?

Comment: No, it's a table (view) method; a search of the (updated) model _should_ find a matching key. The need to convert indices is something to keep in mind as you debug.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Jtable header to sort it, and click on a row (ex. 3rd row), you will get the value of unsorted JTable's row. To avoid this situation, use this LOC.(ik this is irrelvant to what you're trying to do but for others w/ similar problems)

```
int row = tblUser.getSelectedRow();
//Without below line, the value you get would be the row before sorting
int correctModel = tblUser.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
//Get username and use it to find its corresponding tuple
String username = (tblUser.getModel().getValueAt(correctModel, 1)).toString();
```

My table looks like this and Im trying to get the username of the selected row and w/o the 2nd LOC, I'd get the unsorted JTable's row value even after sorting it:

```
---------------------
|  id    |   username |
---------------------
|        |            |
```